# Returning cursor isn't retrieving data from DB

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.3

cursor.execute(sql_statement)
conn.close()
return cursor

the above are the closing lines of my program. I've 3 html pages (users, workflows, home), returning curosor is triggering data for workflows and  home page, but not for users page

Where as, if i do return cursor.fetchall(), then it's working for all 3 pages.

The reason why i want to return cursor is, the client might want to iterate or do other processing on the cursor.

I'm not sure what am doing different with Users page.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the connection, you cannot iterate a cursor anymore. There is no connection to the database.

Comment: If that's the case, why is it working for other 2 html pages? Also, i just tried switching conn.close and return cursor lines and it's still the same, thanks for looking man!